# QGIS Heatmap values change when imported into ArcMap?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, heat-map, geotiff-tiff

I am creating a heatmap layer from QGIS and importing the TIFF into ArcMap. When I import the file into ArcMap I notice that values are different.

For example the max value in QGIS is 8.92454, but after I add the same layer to ArcMap the max value becomes 21.8739.

Does anyone know why this is so? Do I need to convert the TIFF into another format before adding to ArcMap?

Comment: Where do you read these max values? (which tool/info box)

Comment: For Arcmap and QGIS I am looking at the table of contents.

Comment: Are you sure QGIS isn't computing some percentiles rather than actual min/max?

Comment: I also notice that when I use the Idetify tool in Qgis the value column says no data. This does not happen i ArcMap

Comment: I am not sure how to find that out. I am using the heatmap extension and input the required fields. When I run the heatmap process I selected raw values in the "output values" drop down box.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6DWTdPT6Df-fmpUOVYzaTdWSjJSdHRaOFM0X0VDenN0dmp4X2otTTdHaFVuOHRrX1M4WnM&usp=sharing Here is a link to the data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8.9 is the 98th percentile which QGIS computes by default for the rendering. If you change to **min/max** and press **Load**, QGIS computes 21.9, just like Arc.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am still having a problem though. After I choose Min/Max and hit apply nothing changes. I also seclected the Min/Max option, hit okay and the number still stays the same. When I re-open the properties tab QGIS still has cumulative count cut selected.

Comment: Click load and then apply